# CodeCommit fails when after commit rewrite with --amend

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codecommit, ebcli

We are using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and eb cli for deployment.

One problem we stumbled upon is not being able to rewrite commits.

When trying to deploy with `eb deploy` after runnig `git commit --amend` , we get the following error:

> ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - "Error making request to CodeCommit: Could not retrieve 0fb2ddf61003f05e67aeabe... (Service: AWSCodeCommit; Status Code: 400; Error Code: CommitIdDoesNotExistException; Request ID: bee56acc-201b-4a3f-...-...)"

How can we overcome that and deploy after running `git commit --amend` ?

**SOLUTION:**

`eb codesource local`, to disable CodeCommit integration.

Apparently CodeCommit was strangely partially integrated. It was performing some sort of tracking - thus the error, but when running `eb use --source codecommit/myrepo/mybranch` it was failing:

> ERROR: NotFoundError - CodeCommit branch not found:

Anyone who can shed some more light on the subject would be welcome.

Comment: I've long wondered what the point of CodeCommit was. This solution is perfect. Just turn it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading "[Configuring additional branches and environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli-codecommit.html#eb-cli-codecommit-config) ", and considering any amend will rewrite the history (at least change the HEAD commit), you might noeed to:

- force push
- re-specify the branch source to use for eb environment

That is:

```sh
git push --force
eb use --source my-app/myBranch <eb-environment>
```

The [OP Gapi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14346848/gapi) reports actually having to desactivate codecommit:

```
eb codesource local
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and got:
ERROR: InvalidOptionsError - Source location "repo..." is not supported by the EBCLI

Comment: @Gapi I don't know the syntax well enough, but check the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-use.html. I might have missed a `codecommit/` in there.

Comment: Thanks, it was still failing - not finding the branch. For now I had "sovled" it by disabling CodeCommit integration (see my edited question).

Comment: @Gapi OK. I have updated the answer and will check if I find anything explaining why such a step is necessary

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal use

```
eb codesource local
eb create <env name>
```